# How to install Haskell with GLUT and OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, haskell, glut

Please help me to install Haskell with support of OpenGL and GLUT. I can't seem to find a tutorial that works in any place.
I found some tutorials, but I get errors.

1. [One here](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/Installation-of-GLUT-package-td3098963.html)
2. [Second one here](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2007-September/031535.html)

The errors are many like the following :

Configuring GLUT-2.2.2.1...
Setup.hs: At least the following dependencies are missing:
OpenGL >=2.3, StateVar -any, Tensor -any

Edit 1: OS : Windows 7 Professional with SP1.
        I'm using Haskell platform and the following components aren't installed by default.

Edit 2:
        Cabal isn't installed, just checked the list of packages installed with haskell platform, and had to install it by hand.

Comment: What OS? If on Ubuntu, try `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev`.

Comment: What makes you say they aren't installed? Perhaps you're just misinterpreting an error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both OpenGL and GLUT are included in the Haskell Platform. Simply visit http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/ to find out how to install it.

Whenever you need to use Haskell, it is always best to install the Haskell Platform instead of just downloading the GHC compiler and installing it on its own. The Haskell Platform includes both GHC and also the most common libraries that you'll need. It also gives you access to the cabal-install program, which can be used to easily install any other packages you might need (When you have installed the platform, use `cabal help` in a terminal to find out more).

Comment: If you don't have these packages, it means there was an error while installing the Haskell Platform. These packages **are** included.

Comment: cabal isn't included in the haskell platform

Comment: @Floradu88: [Yes, it is](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/contents.html#developer-tools).

Comment: I installed the Haskell platform and still didnt work, I even have opengl libraries installed and C programs work just fine. I dont understand why everything with haskell has to be so complicated. I get *** Exception: user error (unknown GLUT entry glutInit)